# ls: Can't find a directory with all permissions present

Tags: linux

can't ls directory even though it exists and even have 777 permissions.
`ls: cannot access /webroot: No such file or directory`
What could be the problem?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: If you do repost then please show the exact command you ran as well as the exact output showing the permissions of the directory.